# django- trouble with mixins

Tags: python, django

so i was attempting to follow the django docs- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#using-formmixin-with-detailview

essentially I'm making a stackoverflow clone using django.
people can ask questions, which can be responded to with answers

now i can make it work if i provide a link that brings them to a seperate page to submit their answer. but that sucks. i want the answer form to be on the question page

based on the docs i came to this code

urls.py-

`url(r'^view/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.QuestionDetail.as_view(),name='detail'),`

views.py-

```
class QuestionDetail(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = QuestionDisplay.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = Answer.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

which (i believe) should render one view for a post request and a different one for a get request

```
class QuestionDisplay(generic.DetailView):
  model = Question
  template_name = 'questions/question_detail.html'

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
      context = super(QuestionDisplay, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
      context['form'] = AnswerForm()
      return context
```

^ this part works fine

```
class Answer(SingleObjectMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'questions/question_detail.html'
    form_class = AnswerForm
    model = Answer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
        self.object = self.get_object()
        return super(Answer, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('questions:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```

^ the problem (i think) when i attempt to submit an answer in the form provided on the page i get a 404 page not found error. specifically

Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/questions/view/8/
Raised by:  questions.views.QuestionDetail

edit that made it work-

```
class QuestionDetail(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = QuestionDisplay.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pk = kwargs['pk']
        view = add_answer_to_question(request, pk)
        return redirect('questions:detail', pk=kwargs['pk'])

def add_answer_to_question(request, pk):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AnswerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            answer = form.save(commit=False)
            answer.question = question
            answer.user_id = request.user.id
            answer.save()
            return redirect('questions:detail', pk=question.pk)
    else:
        form = AnswerForm()
    return render(request, 'answers/_answer_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if you use `ModelForm`,and the error is something related with the method `get_success_url`.

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse_lazy('questions:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.instance.pk})
```

and you must set `app_name='questions'` in your urls.py.

Comment: nope same problem :-/ the issue isn't in the redirect, the problem is that the page wont load with a post request in the first place

Comment: Is something wrong wit `post method in QuestionDetail`, i never see someone write redirect like this,you can use `HttpResponseRedirect` instead.

Comment: has a test like `view = Answer.as_view() return view(request, *args, **kwargs)`,both post and get mothod work fine.

Comment: try add `url(r'^answer/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.Answer.as_view(),name='answer')` to your urls.py

Comment: some improve,`add_answer_to_question` only called in post method,you can reformat your code by move code in `add_answer_to_question` to `post method in QuestionDetail`,if you take `add_answer_to_question` method as class `Answer`,just ignore it.

Comment: I edited it this morning. yesterday I just wanted to post my code as soon as i found the solution (i had been working on that problem for about 4 hours and was quite tired)